# HTML string append/replace in PHP

Tags: php, html, string

I have the following html string in my php code:

```
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/123456789" width="604" height="340" frameborder="0" title="Ovarian Psycos - Teaser" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

I want to append parameters to the URL give in the `src` attribute. The result should look as follows:

```
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/123456789/APPENDAGE" width="604" height="340" frameborder="0" title="Ovarian Psycos - Teaser" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

As you can see, in my example the string `/APPENDAGE` should be appended to the URL givein in the `src` attribute.

Usually I would do something like this with a string-replace method, however, in the given case this approach won't work. What would be an efficient approach to reach my goal?

Comment: What have you tried, can you share some of your work.

Comment: i have tried string replacement function, but it doesn't work due to the lack of "input string" that should be replaced because the video ID (e.g. 123456789 can be different each time)

Comment: I'd be loading your HTML up with DomDocument or SimpleXML and finding the nodes that way.

Comment: Where do you get the "iframe"-String from? If it's hardcoded in PHP you can simply add the value to it, also why is replace not working what have you tried?

Comment: it's not hardcoded. replace does not work because the id can change.

Comment: Could you not just drop into php and echo the append value within the iframe tag?

Comment: no, because i get the html as a variable `$html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind using regex, there is a simple solution for this: ([DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/270Rdc/1))

```
$str = '<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/123456789" width="604" height="340" frameborder="0" title="Ovarian Psycos - Teaser" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
';

$replaced = preg_replace('/(?<=src=")(.*?)(?=")/', '$1/APPENDAGE', $str);

var_dump($replaced);
```

Output:

```
string '<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/123456789/APPENDAGE" width="604" height="340" frameborder="0" title="Ovarian Psycos - Teaser" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
' (length=215)
```

This will simply match the url, insdie `src` attr and append `/APPENDAGE` to it, you can change it to whatever you want.

Comment: thanks. it will add `/APPENDAGE` and not just `APPENDAGE` right?

Comment: @beta Yes, as you can see `'$1/APPENDAGE'` there is a `/` between the `$1` and `APPENDAGE`

Comment: yes, i know. but in your last sentences you only write `APPENDAGE` and not `/APPENDAGE`.

Comment: @beta Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't mind a large code

```
<?php
 $str = '<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/123456789" width="604" height="340" frameborder="0" title="Ovarian Psycos - Teaser" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>';

$obj = simplexml_load_string($str);
//print_r($obj);
$obj['src'] = $obj['src'].'/APPENDAGE';
$s = $obj->asXML();

print(substr( $s, strpos($s, "\n")+1 ));
```

But this code will also work for rest of the attributes